# Optimal use of Backbone.Marionette template cache

Tags: django-templates, memcached, marionette

I'm using Django in conjunction with Backbone.marionette.

I have a base.html with nested Marionette regions/layouts. I noticed that [Marionette has a template cache framework](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.templatecache.md) which will cache everything in script blocks.

With that said, instead of extending the base.html in Django to accommodate slightly differing layouts, what are the pros and cons of simply using a single base.html containing all the script blocks for the necessary Marionette regions. Considering that I only have 3 - 4 different pages that will be loaded on a regular basis, this would keep things DRY and neatly packaged.